# Binary to String in MongoDb Java

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

Hello I'm using MongoDb database and I have to put all the content of the websites inside of a MongoDb database as a Binary form. Now in the servlet part I need to get id and convert bson binary into String to write in iFrames. How can I convert binary to string in MongoDb using Java?

**JAVA CODES.**

```
    //Not quite working.

    public String giveSelected(String id){
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbTest");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("colTest");
    Document myDoc = collection.find(eq("_id", id)).first();
    String str=myDoc.getString("content");
    return str;
}
```

**JSP CALL:**

```
 //str is the String form of needed content Binary.
 <script>
 function iFramefunc(){
 var s = document.getElementById('iframe');
 s.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML="<%=str%>";
 s.contentDocument.close();
 }
 </script>
 <iframe id="iframe" onload="iFramefunc()"></iframe>
```

Comment: That mainly depends on the code that creates that binary representation of your website. So, how does that part work? And why don't you just reverse that? Btw, that sounds like an "interesting" approach, to store websites as BLOBs in databases.

Comment: Binary stores less data in MongoDb, it takes them automatically in another program. All I need is to take them as binary objects and change it to a String.

Comment: Still: the **essence** is *takes them automatically in another program* ... that process defines the content of your database. You can't reverse that operation when you dont understand it. Maybe there is base64 encoding, maybe there is compression, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also compress the content and store that compressed binary data. Here's an example:

```
private static byte[] compress(String str) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    gzip.close();
    byte[] compressedString = obj.toByteArray();
    return compressedString;
}

private static String uncompress(byte[] compressedContent) throws IOException {
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressedContent));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));
    String line;
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(line);
    }  
    return out.toString();
}

private static void readWrite() throws IOException {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbTest");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("colTest");
    collection.drop();

    // Write
    String str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBccccccccccccccccccc";
    byte[] compressedString = compress(str);
    String id = "abc";
    Document doc = new Document("content", compressedString).append("_id", id);
    collection.insertOne(doc);

    // Read
    Document myDoc = collection.find(eq("_id", id)).first();
    byte[] compressedContent = ((Binary)myDoc.get("content")).getData();
    String content = uncompress(compressedContent);
    System.out.println(content);
}
```